# How should I display the areas where a user is having trouble

Tags: website-design, web-app, bootstrap, metrics

I am developing a website for a school project in which my fellow students can log in and prepare for upcoming exams. They are currently able to practice through flashcards and a memory game, and I will be adding more ways to practice later. The focus is around vocabulary terms and I am tracking when a user gets a word correct or incorrect. On the user's page I would like to display the words that she is struggling with. Normally I would display the percent correct in a table in order by highest percent, but I feel that the user would not get much out of that.

Comment: Welcome to UX.stackexchange. What would you like the users to get from the display? How well their doing (in comparison to what)? How about startgin off by simply displaying the words they're getting wrong with the most frequently missed at the top of the list?

Comment: so what you want is just to show the words that the studens have got wrong the most?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about trying to use some kind of wordmap API to generate a wordmap based off of how often they missed specific words.

You could create an array of words, repeating the word bassed of the ratio of correct:incorrect matches, and pass that onto a wordmap api.

This way, you could get a more visual representation instead of a quantitative representation which would be easier to understand, and users could see bigger words shrink as they study more.

Answer (score 0):

Given your question, is this the sort of thing you're trying to do?

[image: Word Correction]

Comment: Yes. Currently the users are responsible for determining if they knew it or if they didn't and I am just recording the data

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you'd like to display the individual words together. You could display the words in a list but with heat or temperature colour coding. For example start with a dark red for the words they get wrong frequently and then move towards orange as they get each word wrong less often.

[image: temptable]

So in the above image the user gets the word "wrong" wrong the most, "something" wrong less often and "easier" wrong even less often.